# How to lower IL nesting depth?

Tags: c#, ndepend

I am giving NDepend a try for 2 weeks now. I still couldn't really figure it out on how to lower `ILNestingDepth`. I have few methods left marked as "Methods too complex - critical". And as a fix method they suggest to seperate method into smaller methods. But I couldn't fix it that way. Let me show you a method:

**First Version:** *ILNesting Depth of Appropriate = 7*

```
public bool Appropriate ( CompanyQuota available, CompanyQuota used )
{
    /// - larger than available or 
    /// - less than already used area
    return !( DiskQuota > available.DiskQuota || DiskQuota < used.DiskUsage ||
        UploadQuota > available.UploadQuota || UploadQuota < used.UploadUsage ||
        DownloadQuota > available.DownloadQuota || DownloadQuota < used.DownloadUsage ||
        PersonnelQuota > available.PersonnelQuota || PersonnelQuota < used.PersonnelUsage );
}
```

**Second Version:** *ILNesting Depth of Appropriate = 7*

```
public bool Appropriate ( CompanyQuota available, CompanyQuota used )
{
    /// - larger than available or 
    /// - less than already used area
    return AvailableFromTop(available) || AvailableFromBottom(used);
}

bool AvailableFromTop ( CompanyQuota available )
{
    return !( DiskQuota > available.DiskQuota ||
        UploadQuota > available.UploadQuota ||
        DownloadQuota > available.DownloadQuota ||
        PersonnelQuota > available.PersonnelQuota );
}

bool AvailableFromBottom ( CompanyQuota used )
{
    return !( DiskQuota < used.DiskUsage ||
            UploadQuota < used.UploadUsage ||
            DownloadQuota < used.DownloadUsage ||
        PersonnelQuota < used.PersonnelUsage );
}
```

How does it really work?

What should I really do?

Comment: This looks like false positive reported by the ILNestingDepth metric. We will investigate this, but clearly you can ignore these issues.

Comment: It's a pity than. Thank you for the response though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Patrick from NDepend team says on the comments this was a false positive report. Hence this question does not need an answer.

For the sake of the community I am keeping this question here with the answer containing only the comment of Patrick, for the "too-lazy-to-read-comments" people.